# Discord auto join server

Tags: python, discord.py

When I run the code I get status code 400 and im unsure on how to fix it so it gets 200.

its meant to auto join  a discord server using python requests and my discord token.

```
#base url
url = "https://discord.com/api/v10/invites/{}"
headers = {
    "Authorization":"mydiscordtoken"
}

r = requests.post(url.format("N5sCvu4C"), headers=headers, json={})
print(r.status_code) #prints 200 if all went well
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the response.text?

Comment: According to [Discord doc](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication), you also need to provide the token type. So try this for the header instead: `"Authorization": f"Bearer {mydiscordtoken}"`